Placing nodes as the root of a tree-like graph
I am new to TikZ and am trying to draw a huge graph generated from data. This graph only contains a couple of cycles and is otherwise a tree-like structure. The problem I am running into is that I want to place these cycles as a "root" of the graph, i.e. either on the bottom or on the top of the graph and draw the rest of a graph like a tree leading to these cycles. I have tried to do the following:
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\tikz [node distance=1.3cm, tree layout]
{
  \foreach \i in {14,15,20,23,24}
    \node (\i) [fill=gray!50, text=black, circle] {\i};

  \draw 
  (14) edge[->] (24) 
  (15) edge[->] (24) 
  (20) edge[->] (24)  
  (23) edge[->] (24) 
  (24) edge[->] (20);
}
\end{document}

But this yields the following:

Which is not good since the cycle between 20 and 24 is placed in the middle of graph instead of the top or bottom. Ideally 20 and 24 would be placed at the top or bottom and 15, 14, 23 would be placed as though they were children of 24 in a tree (EDIT: see the bottom picture). But I can't quite figure out a way to do this, such that I can algorithmically generate hundreds of edges and nodes to fill this tree out (here i mean that the LaTeX-code is sufficently simple to allow a computer program to easily make it).
EDIT: I realized after some prodding from the kind people on here, that it was not clear what I was talking about when referring to the correct placement of 20 and 24. I mean that I want them to be placed like this (I also added some extra nodes to illustrate why I think it makes sense to place them like this):


Can you add a sketch how the result should look like?

Do you mean something like this?

I think it will be easier, especially if you want to generate the code programmatically, to use the graphing syntax. This way you're specifying the relationships between the nodes in a more fine-grained way, even though the actual specification is more concise.
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs}
\usegdlibrary{trees}

\begin{document}
\tikz
{
  \graph [tree layout, nodes={fill=gray!50, circle}, node distance=13mm]
  {
    20 <-> 24 <- {14,15,23}
  };
}
\end{document}

That is, your original code specifies the relationship between pairs of nodes after they have been placed. But the graphing libraries are designed to take account of the relationships when determining node placement, which is probably what you want for graphs utilising large numbers of nodes generated from data.

Thank you so much for the help! :) I tried looking into that way of writing graphs but i couldn't figure out how to get it to work with a very important cycle in my graph, which is 6 -> 12 -> 16 -> 6. Do you know of a way write that cycle in graphing syntax, remembering that i also need to make a tree-like structure from each of the nodes, i.e. 6, 12 and 16?
